# I would like to use this callback inside of a function that has a callback

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to receive a list of files using this block of code:

```
var templates;
db.getTemplates(function(err, reply){
    templates = reply;
});
```

from this block of code, but node is complaining "undefined is not a function", why is callback undefined? And more importantly what is the best way to write this?

```
function getTemplates(callback){
fs.readdir('views/templates', function(err, reply){
    if(err){
        callback('there was an error reading the directory: ' + err, null);
    } else{
        callback(null, reply);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: From which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: The Error is being thrown from the second callback. Inside the else. However if I remove the else block it will get thrown from the first callback inside the if(err) block.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the snippets you've posted, as long as `db.getTemplates` references `function getTemplates()`: http://jsfiddle.net/rbm03tc5/. Is `getTemplates()` used anywhere else that might not provide an argument value for `callback`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue. I had to place callback inside of an if statement to make the code run. Example:

```
function getTemplates(callback){
    fs.readdir('views/templates', function(err, reply){
    if(callback){    
        if(err){
            callback('there was an error reading the directory: ' + err, null);
        } else{
        callback(null, reply);
    }
}
});
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you would need to do that unless you are not giving a callback sometimes which would probably be bad.